# How to use one Gradle task's inputs as inputs for a second task

Tags: gradle

Use case: I have multiple tasks that populate a directory.  I only want to clear that directory when the inputs to those 2 tasks have changed.  The below is a simplified case.

```
.
├─ build.gradle
└── myFolder
    ├─ toBeDeleted.txt
    └─ mySubFolder
       └─ toBeCopied.txt
```

build.gradle

```
def myFolder = "${projectDir}/myFolder"
def mySubFolder = "${projectDir}/myFolder/mySubFolder"

task copyFiles(type:Copy, dependsOn: ['deleteFiles']) {
    from (mySubFolder) {
        include "toBeCopied.txt"
    }
    into myFolder
}


task deleteFiles() {
    inputs.files copyFiles.outputs.files

    doLast {
        System.out.println(">>deleteFiles :: doLast");
    }
}
```

goal: only perform `deleteFiles` actions when the inputs of `copyFiles` have changed.

Comment: both tasks have to have changed inputs or if at least one of them has changed input, the folder should be cleared?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following

- Each copy task would need to depend on ‘deleteFiles’
- ‘deleteFiles’ input needs to be the input of all inputs of ‘copyFile#‘ tasks

This way ‘deleteFiles’ will execute before any ‘copy’ task, and will also execute when any input changes. You can’t reference output from task2 in task1 if task1 is supposed to execute first that doesn’t make sense.

I don’t know you use case but it doesn’t usually make sense to force delete like this because it removes the benefit of incremental builds.